# FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD no longer working on Android Lollipop?

Tags: android

As the title says, I've been surprised to find that FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD flag is no longer functioning on API 21 (Lollipop).

In kitkat, setting this flag would dismiss an insecure keyguard.

So is this a feature or a bug? What's the workaround?

Disabling keyguard via PowerManager class is an option, but it can't work like dismissal style. Can it?

Comment: Anyone? I'm surprised developers wrote about this problem in their release notes, but there's no mention of it all over the internet. Nobody even acknowledges it officially

Comment: It's a bug. https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1902

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: It's a bug.

Second, Is there a workaround? Yes.

Because I stumpled upon this issue and even google did not know this issue,
I made a tremendous research on how to work around this.
It's quite easy. The bug is presumably that the keyguard is registered two
times android intern.

The trick is to start a *pre running* activity in forehand, listening to 
screen on broadcasts, dismissing the keyguard and start your real intented 
activity.

Code:

```
public class KeyGuardDismissActivity extends Activity {

    private ScreenOnReceiver receiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LOG.d("Start keyguard dismisser!");
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            startActivity(new SomeOtherActivityIntent(getApplicationContext()));
            finish();
            return;
        }
        this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        receiver = new ScreenOnReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, receiver.getFilter());
    }

    private void dismissingKeyguard() {
        LOG.d("Dismissing keyguard!");
        SomeOtherActivityIntent yourRealActivity = new SomeOtherActivityIntent(getApplicationContext(), this);
        startActivity(yourRealActivity );
        if (receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
        }
        finish();
    }

    private class ScreenOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            LOG.d("Screen on, yay!");
            dismissingKeyguard();
        }

        public IntentFilter getFilter() {
            IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
            filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

**In your real activity you have to add the dismiss flag, too!**

Greetings.

Comment: So is it possible to apply the dismiss keyguard flag twice to achieve the same result? Any specific reason behind using another listener?

Comment: No sorry, it's a flag. You need two windows. flag |= flag == flag

Comment: Any idea why it works if we remove the flag show over lockscreen before adding the dismiss flag? As suggested in the official bug report?

Comment: It won't work on every device, even if you remove the flag show over the lockscreen. Saw the report and tested it. But I can't unfortunately tell you why. I did not write it :)