# FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD no longer working on Android with custom Locker

Tags: android, android-launcher, keyguard

I have two nexus 4 in 5.1.1.
One have the go locker and the other Google launcher.

I launch activity with alarmmanger and in the activity I have this:

```
getWindow().addFlags(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

On the nexus which don't have the go locker, the keyguard is dismissed but on the other it didn't.

The Google clock, dismiss the keyguard so I think it's possible.

I have try this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948419/flag-dismiss-keyguard-no-longer-working-on-android-lollipop) but it doesn't work.

I try to use this but it doesn't work too:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    m_keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("keyguardLockWakeLock");
    m_keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```